# Join query with multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, sum

Below is my query, and what i do is:

1) from the ADV_CAMP table i am taking the id of ADV_PACK; its table's id is stored in VIEWCAMP table.

These are relations between the tables.

The total amount for ADV_CAMP data is stored in ADV_PACK table, and the amount spend for the ADV_CAMP table is stored in VIEWCAMP.

2) So i need to take two random values from ADV_CAMP table. The amount spend stored in VIEWCAMP will not exceed the ADV_PACK total amount.

Is there any way to take the data in single query, or any other solution ?

Query :

```
"SELECT *  FROM 
".ADV_CAMP.".c  
LEFT JOIN ".ADV_PACK.".p ON c.adv_pack=p.pack_id  
LEFT JOIN  ".VIEWCAMP.".v ON v.SUM(consumption_amount) > p.pack_credits;"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the column link between ADV_CAMP and VIEWCAMP tables?

Comment: ADV_CAMP id is stored in view camp

Comment: ok, is there a link between ADV_PACK and VIEWCAMP?

Comment: yes there is direct link ADV_CAMP id is stored in view camp . and ADV_PACK id is stored in ADV_CAMP

Answer (score 0):

After the discussion and assuming the link between `ADV_CAMP` and `VIEWCAMP` is done by `id` field in `ADV_CAMP` table and `adv_camp_id` in `VIEWCAMP` table you can try this:

```
SELECT 
    *  
FROM 
    ".ADV_CAMP." as c  
LEFT JOIN ".ADV_PACK." as p 
    ON c.adv_pack=p.pack_id  
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        adv_camp_id,
        SUM(consumption_amount) as za_sum
    FROM 
        ".VIEWCAMP."
    GROUP BY
        adv_camp_id
) as tmp 
    ON tmp.adv_camp_id = c.id
    AND tmp.za_sum > p.pack_credits
```